# How many parts do 100 lines divide a plane into when no two are parallel and no three pass through the same point?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I started by trying to find a pattern between the number of lines and parts, but it seems to be pretty random. (I may have split the plane incorrectly). Can someone give me a hint to if there is a pattern or a clear method?

Comment: For two lines the number of regions is 4, for 3, it is 7, for 4 it is 11. If the number of regions for $n$ lines is $R_n$, for $n+1$ lines, it will be $R_n+n+1$

Comment: ... because, when you add a new line, it crosses each of the old lines exactly once.

Comment: If no lines are parallel and no three pass through the same point the every pair of lines intersect at one point.  Each of n lines intersects with each of the n-1 other lines so there are a total of n(n- 1) points of intersection.  Now use "Euler's (geometric) formula", for the plane:  the fact that, for a plane, f- e+ v= 1 where f is the number of "faces" (regions bounded by the lines), e is the number of edges (lines), and v is the number of vertices (points where lines intersect.

Comment: @user247327 Then the answer would be 9801.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: think of the problem as a planar graph in which the intersections of lines are vertices and the line segments are edges. In order to actually get a graph you can add a huge circle outside the graph so that the lines don't go to infinity).

Then apply euler's formula. The number of segments and vertices is easy to calculate inductively.